# R+LaTeX: Проблема с кодировкой осей графика

Tags: r

Возникла проблема с названием осей графика.

```
<<echo=FALSE,size='normalsize',fig.width=5, fig.height=4,results = "asis">>=
result <- read.table(file='results/mydata',sep = ";",nrows = 5,header =TRUE)
p <- ggplot(data = result, aes(y = n, x=r)) +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="orange", formula = y ~ x) +
stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, 
          aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
          parse = TRUE) +         
geom_point() + xlab( expression('r'^-1~'м'))+ ylab( expression('n'~'усл.едн'))
p
```

Когда в названии осей английские буквы все нормально работает, но если ввести российские буквы возникает ошибка:

```
## Warning in grid.Call(L_stringMetric,
as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)): font metrics unknown for
Unicode character U+043c
```

Как видно проблема в том, что текст закодирован в **U+043c**. Я пытался использовать `options("encoding" = "UTF-8")`, не помогло. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать кодировку PDF файла в одном из чанков в начале документа:

```
pdf.options(encoding = "CP1251")
```

Также может помочь смена графического устройства по умолчанию:

```
options(device = "cairo_pdf")
```

Comment: Не помогло :(...